# Scroll to error message of hidden field using jquery validate

Tags: jquery

I have a form, i used jquery validate method to validate the form fields. The error message are showing properly. I have hidden fields in my form where i need to perform validations on hidden fields. I used **ignore** for validating hidden fields that to worked fine. But after displaying the error message the form is not scrolling to the error message of hidden field. For other fields(text type) that is working fine. Thanks in advance

```
<input type="hidden" name="type_hidden_field" class="form-control" value >
$("#upload_data").validate({ 
  rule:{
       "type_hidden_field":
        {
            required:true,
        }
   },
  messages:{
     "type_hidden_field":{
      required:"error message",
      },
  },
 errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');

        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
 });
```

Comment: Before down voting can you specify the reason

Comment: Did you check the console?
Always when i try to validate hidden fields, the console sais:"cann not focus a hidden field" so.. `type=hidden` is not displayed so you cant scroll to this position. if you call `offset` on a hidden element it will return both 0

Comment: There are no error messages in my console. And one point i need to mention is I have not written any code to scroll, just used  highlight.

Comment: seems to be that the hidde field cant be highlighted. Maybe you can switch on the type of the input and caluclate the position of the inputs parent and scroll to this position... want have a animated scroll? : `.animate( {scrollTop: value} );`